# Vue js application context name change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router, vue-cli

How to change Vue js application context name?

I added a public path in Vue config js file, but it is not hitting URL with public pathname.

I could see compilation happened with the public path name:

> INFO  Starting development server...  98% after emitting CopyPlugin
>
> DONE  Compiled successfully in 4793ms
>   5:38:57 PM
>
> App running at:
>     - Local:   http://localhost:8080/testapp/ 
>     - Network: http://192.168.104.88:8080/testapp/
>
> Note that the development build is not optimized.   To create a
>   production build, run yarn build.

### In vue.config.js

```
module.exports = 

{ 
    publicPath: '/testapp/',
    devServer: {
      disableHostCheck: true
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it is not hitting URL with public pathname"? Does the local  url work and what do you get when you navigate to the public url?

Comment: Yes it is not hitting URL with public pathname.

Comment: Local URL is not working. if I hit local URL http://localhost:8080/testapp/  then getting blank page with 304 HTTP status code